# How to make an uploaded video visible on the node page in drupal 7

Tags: 7, files, entities

I have created a CCK named **sample** with a field name **VIDEOS** of type **file**. I have added a video of CCK type Sample. But it only showed a url after the node is saved.[image]

Instead of displaying the file name how to make the video playable on the same page.

I installed jwplayer in libraries. I tried changing display type From **Generic** to **JWplayer**

[image]

Was trying since past 2 days using video module, VideoJS. But did not succeeded. Please help.

**UPDATE**

here is the result which i got when working with **Video** module
[image]

It is returning empty data with Play button on it. No video is displayed

**UPDATE**

A small progress,Tried **Flow Player**  flv videos are able to play. but mp4 is not playing. It simply shows a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Video](https://drupal.org/project/video) module. You can create field type video insted of type file and then upload and render with the player you have configured.

Comment: Yes i tried. i choose field type Video. let me update my post with a snapshot

Comment: I updated my post please have a look

Comment: Try going to Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » Video » Players and select JWplayer for extensions *.mp4, also you can try the flowplayer module - if so select the flowplayer player for *.mp4 and give it a try.

Comment: Ya sure. I will let u know. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have gone through the formats and changed the player to FLV player and then there is a sub category called jwplayer. But Still the video did not appeared. I think something wrong with jwplayer. IS there any perfect Documentation for JwPlayer. I think there is no stable version for Drupal7

Comment: well if you suspect that there is an issue with the jwplayer, try installing flowplayer and play with it.

Comment: hi @ivan Ivanov i tried flow player. Thanks for the module suggestion, It really worked with flv formats. But mp4 is not working It just displays Black Screen with out controls. What might be the reason. Any thing to work with server configuration?

Comment: hmm, is it possible the video you are trying with to be broken, have you tried with several .mp4 files? because it is kinda strange that the .flv works and .mp4 does not, they are very similar formats from player's prespective.

Comment: dunno what are you trying to achieve but you can try this: clean new drupal installation, install video module then flowplayer, then create a video field and upload some .mp4 videos - it should work 100%, Ive done it some many times. If the video doesn't work it is very likely to be an issue with the environment where you are working or an issue with the video file itslef.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the display to "rendered File" in the display settings for the content type? If uploading as a file, might work for you.[image: Screenshot of video content type display settings]

Comment: There are only two options Video Player and Video Video Thumbnail, nothing like rendered File @Daniel

Comment: OK, got ya, sorry, I think "Rendered File" requires the  [Media Module](https://drupal.org/project/media) in order to show up as an option. Maybe install that, and check if it helps. I have had good luck just utilizing that module for video work. Just create a field with "field type: file", then under display, rendered file. If you don't want to go that route, what does the rendered source code for your blank video look like (that you posted above)?

Comment: Hi @Daniel i tried using Media Module. No luck. Yes i have selected rendered file option, also experimented with view mode to Original but no use. Displaying same old link. Do we need any libraries or plugin to make the video play?